# How can I organize data with Google Analytics?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I'm developing an app that sends emails with attachments and I've added google analytics to track senders, receivers,attachments and the date when the email was sent,I create events with all these information in the same label , it works perfectly but my problem is that I want to organize these data in one array with 4 columns :**sender**, **receiver**,**attachments** and **date**.I've found in the developer guide that Custom Dimensions & Metrics could be a solution, so I implemented the associated code:

```
 [tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1] value:sender];
      [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker] send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder    createScreenView] set:@"sender" forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1]] build]];
 [tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:2] value:receiver];
      [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker] send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder    createScreenView] set:@"receiver" forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:2]] build]];
 [tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:3] value:date];
      [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker] send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder    createScreenView] set:@"date" forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:3]] build]];
 [tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:4] value:attachments];
      [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker] send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder    createScreenView] set:@"attachments" forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:4]] build]];
```

And I've created 4 custom dimensions in the admin section of my google analytics account.What I can't understand here is how google analytics could make links between these data to show theme in a same array under custom rapports.

this the configuration of the custom report:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v08tk.png)
and here where the data should be shown
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7EwZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom report by hitting the "Customisation" button at the top when logged into Google Analytics.  You should then be able to find your custom dimensions in the drop down lists, and add the metrics you require.

Comment: I did what you just say (I edited my question and uploaded two images)but I can't see any results, may be it should take some time to appear

Comment: Yes, need to wait 24 hours, although you may be able to see something in a couple of hours.

Comment: It works in real time , you've  just to indicate the date in the dropdown list, I changed it to Today.That's all.

Comment: ok cool, thats not always the case, but glad it works here.  GA Premium has an SLA of data appearing in 4 hours, so you're doing better than that :)

Comment: Does GA groups data for every user in the same row or it just list incoming data? In other word if two users send an email at the same time,will'I get automatically a row for each user?

Comment: if you have a unique dimension for each and put it into a custom dimension, then you can get what you are asking.  But otherwise, no it will aggregate.  You can get a row for each dimension combination you send in.

Comment: what do you mean by unique dimension for each?Do I miss something in the configuration section of the custom dimension?

Comment: I mean you get a row for each unique combination of dimensions - so if you have configured a unique userId for each user as a dimension, for example, then each row would be for one user.